# Solidity function calls from javascript work locally but fail on ropsten,kovan etc with Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, javascript, nodejs

I have a smart contract whose function calls works fine when called locally using javascript and ganache.
But when I deploy to ropsten and others, the calls to its functions fail with

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
```

Since I was calling Orfeed's `getExchangeRate` function, I initially thought it was Orfeed that was acting up. But then I added a simple function like this:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
    contract HelloThere  {
    
    function hallo() external pure returns(string memory){
        return "Hallo!!!";
    }
    
    }
```

and called the function from javascript like this:

```
  contractObj.methods.hallo().call().then((result) => {
            console.log("za-then construct -->>",result);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('err...\n'+err);
        });
```

This works fine when deploying locally to ganache.

But once I deploy to ropsten, I get the errors:

```
error Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226:15)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:465:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:818:46)
    at Method.formatOutput (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:163:54)
    at sendTxCallback (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:473:33)
    at /Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:505:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Here is my **truffle-config.js:**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');
 
const envConfig = dotenv.config({silent: true});



 const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
 const infuraKey = process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;

const ethPubAddr = process.env.ETH_PUBLIC_ADDRESS;
 const mnemonic = process.env.METAMASK_PVT_KEY;//fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
 

 console.log("mnemonic -->" , mnemonic);

module.exports = {

  networks: {
   
    mainnet: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/"+infuraKey);
      },
      network_id: '1',
      from: ethPubAddr,

    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/"+infuraKey);
      },
      network_id: '3',
      from: ethPubAddr,   
      gas: 5500000, 

    },
     
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },

   
  },

 
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.6.10",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
     settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
       }
    }

  }
}
```

What could cause this failure? and I have enough gas in my Metamask account...(8.7 Eth)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
Migrations dry-run (simulation)
===============================
> Network name:    'ropsten-fork'
> Network id:      3
> Block gas limit: 8000029 (0x7a121d)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > block number:        8119069
   > block timestamp:     1592470990
   > account:             0xdABB407d281d5d586fB4B68CcFD2EA4a0878Ff90
   > balance:             8.7232663532
   > gas used:            114186 (0x1be0a)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00228372 ETH

   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00228372 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================


   Deploying 'MyApp'
   ----------------
   > block number:        8119071
   > block timestamp:     1592471050
   > account:             0xdEBB407d28.......
   > balance:             8.6793118932
   > gas used:            2170457 (0x211e59)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.04340914 ETH


Starting
Listening on 5000
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.04340914 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.04569286 ETH


Contract Address =  0x4cd65b9662A...



Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226:15)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:465:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:818:46)
    at Method.formatOutput (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:163:54)
    at sendTxCallback (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:473:33)
    at /Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/gbemirojiboye/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:505:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Comment: Can you show a verified contract on EtherScan on Ropsten network? Most likely your contract address is wrong, contract did not deploy correctly, etc.

Comment: I got this:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/8119083

Comment: This is not a smart contract address

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4cd65b9662A9430F0A3c879ad45c1cd8C6B50A58

Comment: Apologies, that right?

Comment: I added the final messages of the deploy stage that shows that deployment succeeds from my end.@MikkoOhtamaa , what do you suspect?

Comment: Everything looks correct. Here are some options I would try out to try to narrow out the issue 1) Verify the contract on Etherscan 2) Try other methods to the new contracts and test them, e.g. send them variable setting transactions 3) Check that Infura node returns a value that there is a smart contract deployed in the address and Infura Ethereum node is not out of sync (happens often with Ropsten because there might be DoS attacks against the testnet)

Comment: I have tried adding new methods that do absolutely nothing other than return a constant string or a number. I got the same error.

I will try the other options you listed, though.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa , some assistance please, how do I carry out your option 3?

Comment: Use `getTransactionReceipt()` to see it get backs the contract deployment tx

Comment: Another idea 4) is that your ABI files are out of date

Comment: Alright will check them both out.
Thanks.

Comment: Where will I check out getTransactionReceipt? in truffle? is it on the web3 object?

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html?highlight=gettransactionreceipt#gettransactionreceipt

Comment: Hi @MikkoOhtamaa , please could you help me take a look at this question?
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/what-token-address-do-i-use-if-i-want-to-sell-an-erc20-token-on-a-different-exch

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I cannot help with the question, as I am not familiar with named contracts and how they operate on Kovan. I suggest you go to Uniswap or Kyber dev channels for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your assistance