# What token address do I use if I want to sell an ERC20 token on a different exchange? Its original address or its address on the other exchange

Tags: blockchain, tokens, uniswap

I really need help with this one to avoid logic errors.

I am on the **Kovan testnet**.

I bought 4 units of *`DAI token`* on *Uniswap exchange*(**`0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D`**) for `0.111 Ether` and tried to sell it on the same exchange; it worked fine.

Then I bought 4 units of *`DAI token`* on *Uniswap exchange* and tried to sell it on *Kyber Exchange*(**`0x692f391bCc85cefCe8C237C01e1f636BbD70EA4D`**); but it failed.

To buy DAI token on Uniswap, I passed it the Uniswap *DAI token address*(**`0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa`**) and to sell the purchased DAI tokens on Kyber exchange, I passed it the address of the Kyber DAI token(**`0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD`**)

Since this didn't work , I decided that Kyber Exchange must want the original address of the DAI tokens on Uniswap, so I passed it instead. It worked.

Though it worked, I am wary of logic errors and I want to be sure:

**Question:**

To sell a Uniswap DAI token on Kyber Exchange, do I pass the Uniswap DAI token address to the kyber exchange or do I use the Kyber DAI token address.

Also, am I allowed to sell across exchanges on testnets like kovan?

Do forgive the naïveté of the question, but I have been quite bothered by it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa` is NOT a contract address according to etherscan!

Comment: Same goes for `0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD`.

Comment: @goodvibration , thanks for responding, they are on Kovan.

See:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x4f96fe3b7a6cf9725f59d353f723c1bdb64ca6aa

and

https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa` and `0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD` aren't the same token. They *are* both tokens on Kovan, but since they aren't the same address, they aren't the same token. According to MakerDAO, the official DAI address on Kovan is the one that Uniswap is using (`0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa`). I believe Kyber just created their own token called DAI to make it easier for them to test their platform on Kovan.

Comment: So, if I buy 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa on Uniswap, and I want to sell it on Kyber, I reference it with the same: 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa, right?

Comment: Correct. The same address is the same token, but it doesn't look like Kyber even has the official Kovan DAI token in their system, so you still wont be able to sell it on Kovan Kyber

Comment: Thanks so much @flygoing. This question has bothered me a lot. Many forums danced around the question and never answered it in a sway I could grasp easily.